# Make ng build output .min.js and .min.js.map instead of .js and .js.map

Tags: angular, minify, angularbuild

I am trying to change the format of the minified code with sourcemaps output by `ng build - c staging`. The current extensions are by default `.js` and `.js.map`. However, I am interested in having the extensions in `.min.js` and `.min.js.map`. Is there any way to that change? I tried to just rename the files with a script, but I do not think that this is the way to proceed.

Thank you all in advance!